# Best strategy for custom errors with common fields in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have implemented [a parser in Rust](https://github.com/gura-conf/gura-rs-parser) that can return [different types of errors](https://github.com/gura-conf/gura-rs-parser/blob/main/src/errors.rs). Previously I had implemented it using different Structs without fields that implemented the `std::error::Error` trait. The issue is that I encountered two problems:

1. The parse function returns a `Box<dyn Error>`, which I find stilted to check what error was returned since I have to fall back to the `.downcast_ref::<SomeCustomError>()` method instead of simply being able to use a match and check what error variant was returned.
2. Now I want all errors to report, with a custom message, *line* *number*, and *position* of the text where the error occurs. This item is easily solved with Structs, but I still fall into the previous problem.

For both reasons is that I want to implement it with Enums. **My question is**: knowing that all variants have the fields pos, line, and message, should I repeat the three fields for all Enum variants? Is there another better way to represent the problem?

What I had in mind was the following code block, but honestly **having to repeat the same code for all variants seems a bit far-fetched** (maybe this could be solved with a macro?):

```rust
use std::fmt;

enum MyCustomError {
    ErrorOne(usize, usize, String),
    ErrorTwo(usize, usize, String)
}

impl fmt::Display for MyCustomError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match &self {
            MyCustomError::ErrorOne(pos, line, message) => {
                write!(
                    f,
                    "{} at line {} position {}",
                    message, line, pos
                )
            },
            MyCustomError::ErrorTwo(pos, line, message) => {
                write!(
                    f,
                    "{} at line {} position {}",
                    message, line, pos
                )
            },
        }
    }
}

fn throw_error() -> Result<(), MyCustomError> {
    Err(MyCustomError::ErrorOne(1, 22, String::from("Error one occurred")))
}


fn main() {
    // Now I can simply use match! :D
    match throw_error() {
        Ok(()) => println!("It works!"),
        Err(err) => {
            match err {
                MyCustomError::ErrorOne(..) => println!("Error one -> {}!", err),
                MyCustomError::ErrorTwo(..) => println!("Error two -> {}!", err),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another alternative could be using [Snafu](https://crates.io/crates/snafu):

```rust
use snafu::Snafu;

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum MyEnum {
    #[snafu(display("{} at line {} position {}", message, line, pos))]
    ErrorOne {
        pos: usize,
        line: usize,
        message: String,
    },
    #[snafu(display("{} at line {} position {}", message, line, pos))]
    ErrorTwo {
        pos: usize,
        line: usize,
        message: String,
    },
}

fn throw_error() -> Result<(), MyEnum> {
    Err(MyEnum::ErrorOne {
        line: 1,
        pos: 22,
        message: String::from("Error one occurred"),
    })
}

fn main() {
    // Now I can simply use match! :D
    match throw_error() {
        Ok(()) => println!("It works!"),
        Err(err) => match err {
            MyEnum::ErrorOne { .. } => println!("Error one -> {}!", err),
            MyEnum::ErrorTwo { .. } => println!("Error two -> {}!", err),
        },
    }
}
```

But I fall into the same problem of repeating the code for each variant.

Comment: Is there a reason not to go with the obvious `enum MyErrorKind { ErrorOne, ErrorTwo(extra_data: u8) }; struct MyError { pos: usize, line: usize, message: String, kind: MyErrorKind }`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've thought about it before, but the fact that it's up to the user to check for the "kind" attribute seemed to me to add a boilerplate to the usage instead of simply comparing with a match as [officially proposed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#matching-on-different-errors). Maybe It's the simpler solution and I could implement PartialEq to compare directly with an error kind Enum

Comment: `PartialEq` doesn't give you structural equality, so you can't `match` on it with the compiler checking all possible variants. But you can simply make the fields `pub`, which allows the user to `match` on it. See [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=472f8acc1c1f5271cb01ad9b57441b4f)

Comment: I didn't know _Pattern binding_. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but two approaches come to my mind:

1. Use a `struct` as follows:

   ```
   struct MyErr {
    line: usize,
    pos: usize,
    actual_err: MyCustomError,
   }
   ```

   Then, you can still `match` on the fild `actual_err`

   ```
   impl fmt::Display for MyCustomError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
         write(f, "{} ", match self.actual_err {
          ErrorOne => "Error 1 Message",
          ErrorTwo => "Error 2 Message",
         })?;
         write!(
                 f,
                 "at line {} position {}",
                 self.line, self.pos
         )
       }
    } 
   }
   ```
2. You could actually try to generate your error variants and the associated `match` statement via macros. Or look into [`enum_dispatch`](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) that could save you some boilerplate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It seems to be the simplest way, I wanted to avoid having the error type as an attribute so I could match directly with the Enum MyCustomError as it does in the [official documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#matching-on-different-errors). As I said in my reply to a comment above, maybe I will implement the PartialEq trait to be able to match with the Enum directly.